# Django custom aggregation

Tags: python, django

I am building a website for mentorship purpose. Wherein, there are logs coming in from the mentors about how did the meeting with his mentee(s) go. As part of dashboard I am exposing/computing-and-exposing the required data.

The Problem statement: Find out the average frequency by which the logs have come in for a collection of mentorships.

My approach:

Step 1. Compute the average frequency i.e. the average of differences between two immediately occurring logs for every mentorship.

Step 2. Compute the average of the average frequencies for each mentorships that is computed in Step 1.

I know that, I'll be needing to group the logs by mentorships and then pass it to a custom aggregate function that would do Step 1 and Step 2. How do I do it in Django? Can someone please help me out with the problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In first place you need to know **where** calculations should be made. They are two possible places, each one with pros and cons.

The first place where to do calculations is in **database layer**. Unfortunately do you not have in django the kind of functions to write the query natively. Then do you need a [raw query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries). Also do you need a DBMS with analytical suport:

```
sql = """    
    with table_with_predates as (
      SELECT Id,
           some_date,
           lag(some_date) pre_date
      FROM menthors
      WINDOW client_window as (partition by client order by idMenthor)
    ) select Id, avg( some_date - pre_date)  as data_average
      from table_with_predates
      group by Id      
    """
menthors = Menthor.objects.raw( sql )
print ( 'Menthor average', menthors[0].name, menthors[0].data_average )
```

Second step may be done with a custom sql. it can be inferred easily from this point.

The second place where to do calculations is in **app layer**. Get log times from model and do the average in python:

```
log_times = ( Log
              .objects
              .filter( menthor = some_menthor )
              .values_list('some_date', flat=True)
            )
menthor_average_log = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, log_times) / len(log_times)
```

Do you have now material to start your code. Enjoy.